# Is there an R function for modifying dataframe for a nested data model?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to modify my dataframe for a nested data model but I can't figure out how to do it using R.

This is my dataframe:

```
idquestionario cod_cartao ord_cartao
             1      33333          5
             1      Death          4
             1      12123          2
             1      22332          3
             1      32332          5
             1      11111          1
            10      23222          7
            10      Death          4
            10      12233          2
            10      33333          4
            10      12111          1
            10      22332          3
...
```

I need to reshape my dataframe to obtain this result:

```
idquestionario cod_cartao cod_cartao
             1      11111      12123
             1      11111      22332
             1      11111      22332
             1      11111      Death
             1      11111      32332
             1      11111      33333
             1      12123      22332
             1      12123      Death
             1      12123      32332
             1      12123      33333
             1      22332      22332
             1      22332      Death
             1      22332      32332
             1      22332      33333
             1      Death      32332
             1      Death      33333
            10      12111      12233
            10      12111      22332
            10      12111      22332
            10      12111      33333
            10      12233      22332
            10      12233      33333
            10      22332      33333
...
```

Just try to explain my dataframe. I have three columns (idquestionario, cod_cartao, ord_cartao)

- idquestionario is an index numeric column
- cod_cartao is the card code used for measure quality of life
- ord_cartao is the ranking of the cards (1 is the best, 2 is the second best and so on). You can have ties in this ranking.

For example the id=1, we have the ranking: 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. The ranking is directly related to the cards:

1 - 11111
2 - 12123
3 - 22332
4 - Death
5 - 33333 and 32332

So I need to match all the cards using the ranking code:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5 Doesn't matter the order
1 5 Doesn't matter the order
2 3
2 4
2 5 Doesn't matter the order
2 5 Doesn't matter the order
3 4
3 5 Doesn't matter the order
3 5 Doesn't matter the order
4 5 Doesn't matter the order
4 5 Doesn't matter the order
```

Thank you for you patience and for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

DT[order(ord_cartao), 
  CJ(cod1 = cod_cartao, cod2 = cod_cartao, sorted = FALSE)[ CJ(V1 = ord_cartao, V2 = ord_cartao, sorted = FALSE)[, V1 < V2] ]
, by=idquestionario]

    idquestionario  cod1  cod2
 1:              1 11111 12123
 2:              1 11111 22332
 3:              1 11111 Death
 4:              1 11111 33333
 5:              1 11111 32332
 6:              1 12123 22332
 7:              1 12123 Death
 8:              1 12123 33333
 9:              1 12123 32332
10:              1 22332 Death
11:              1 22332 33333
12:              1 22332 32332
13:              1 Death 33333
14:              1 Death 32332
15:             10 12111 12233
16:             10 12111 22332
17:             10 12111 Death
18:             10 12111 33333
19:             10 12111 23222
20:             10 12233 22332
21:             10 12233 Death
22:             10 12233 33333
23:             10 12233 23222
24:             10 22332 Death
25:             10 22332 33333
26:             10 22332 23222
27:             10 Death 23222
28:             10 33333 23222
    idquestionario  cod1  cod2
```

*How it works.* The first `CJ` takes the Cartesian combination of the code vectors. The second does the same for the order vectors. The predicate `V1 < V2` is computed for the order vectors and used to filter the table generated for the code vectors.

*Comment.* This seems like an very inefficient way to arrange the data, since the table size will balloon without conveying any additional information. Moreover, it will drop ids for which all codes have the same rank. If you want to store information about ranks differently, maybe use the igraph package with links created by adjacent ranks. I mean a graph like the one pictured near the top here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_poset